# using push function in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, push, angularjs-ng-repeat

i am trying to make a eCommerce shop with angular and code is as follow

```
var shopApp = angular.module('shopApp', ["slugifier"], function() {});

   controllers.productController = function($scope,FetchFactory) {

     $scope.fetchProducts = function(offset) {
        FetchFactory.items.fetchItems(offset).then(function(data){
        $scope.products = data;
    });
  }
  var activeAttrValue = 0;
  var activeAttrUnit = 0;
  var activeAttrId = 0;
   $scope.add_to_cart() = function(index){
        var newProd = [];
        newProd = $scope.products[index]; // $scope.products have products json
        newProd.quantity = 1;
        newProd.attr_id = activeAttrId;
        newProd.attr_value = activeAttrValue;
        newProd.attr_unit = activeAttrUnit;
        $scope.cartProducts.itemlist.push(newProd);
        $scope.cartProducts.total_items++;
        $scope.cartProducts.total_price += parseInt(newProd.price);
   }
 }
 shopApp.controller(controllers);
```

i have a made a factory which will return me products json after a ajax request and using ng-repeat as "product in products" i am displaying all the products in my html and i have make a shopping cart where the products that are added to cart are being displayed by ng-repeat of "cartProduct in cartProducts.itemlist track by $index"
products have attributes like color,size,weight etc. whenever a attribute is clicked its value(like weight) and unit(kg) are store in a global variables activeAttrValue,activeAttrUnit and if add to cart is clicked they are stored in cartProducts.

Problem:
In case of multiple attributes. when one attribute is selected added to cart, and again another attribute of same product is selected and added to cart.ideally they should add to cart as two products but instead last added product and attributes only adds and in console gives a error

```
 Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=cartProduct%20in%20cartProducts.itemlist&p1=object%3A006
```

when i tried console.log($scope.cartProducts.itemlist); 
i got this

```
 Object
   $$hashKey: "005"
   attr_id: "3"
   attr_unit: ""
   attr_value: "blue"
  , 
  Object
   $$hashKey: "005"
   attr_id: "3"
   attr_unit: ""
   attr_value: "blue"
```

attributes of both products changed to same

I hope i am clear with my problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26152576/ngrepeatdupes-duplicates-in-repeater-with-nested-ngrepeat-and-empty-strings/26152601#26152601  and many more i am sure.. You should try search with the error `ngRepeat:dupes`

Comment: Are you trying to push the same item to the array? How about if you do `newProd = angular.clone($scope.products[index]);` In the previous answer posted has information on why you might be seeing this issue. angular.clone should remove `$$hashKey`. Anyways if it same item being pushed into the cart why dont you associate a counter for item, instead of pushing the same object.

Comment: yes same item but with different selected attribute

it worked fine when i tried adding like this
1.product-A with a attribute-1
2.product-B without any attribute
3.product-A with a attribute-2

Comment: its something like i select a blue tee and add to cart .. it has black too.. so i select black and add to the cart. but i find two black tees are added

Comment: That is because you are using same object reference. Use `angular.clone`. Did you check my comment earlier?

Comment: angular.copy worked!! thank you

Comment: oops sorry yeah that was my typo.. i meant angular.copy.. :)

Comment: @PSL now i am calling this $scope.add_to_cart function with js using angular.element().scope().add_to_cart().. the product is being pushed in to cartProducts successfully but in shopping cart it is not displaying.. can you please help me with this

Comment: You need to do scope.apply but you should ideally notaccess scope like that.

Comment: @PSL actually i am trying to make a popup where i can show all the details of the product when clicked on something like quick view.i used js function by passing just the selected product data where i make the html elements to display the details and used bootstrap modal to get the popup. so as this html elements are made after a quick view of a product is clicked i am not able to use any controller in it but i need to access add_to_cart function so i am using angular.element().scope().Can u suggest any alternative for this other that bootstrap-angular-ui..

thank you again for your help..

Answer (score 3):

Angular for default does not allow duplicated elements on ng-repeat.
In order to fix this, you need to add a "track by" in your ng-repeat directive.

For example for a list of numbers with duplicated elements:

```
<div ng-repeat="value in [1, 1, 1, 2, 2] track by $index"></div>
```

For more info check the [url of your error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=cartProduct%20in%20cartProducts.itemlist&p1=object:006)

Answer (score 2):

Try `ng-repeat="cartProduct in cartProducts.itemlist track by $index"`.

Comment: have tried that!! when i tried console.log($scope.cartProducts.itemlist), it shows as two products but attribute of both the products become the last attribute that was selected.